# "file" command confusing C & C++

Tags: files, mime-types

When using `file` to check some file types, I noticed that it seems to incorrectly label C++ files as C files:

```
$ file User.*
User.cpp: C source, ASCII text
User.h:   C++ source, ASCII text
User.o:   ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

Why is it correctly identifying the header file, but not the cpp file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From man page of `file` command,

`file` command actually performs 3 tests on determining the file type.

#### First test

> The filesystem tests are based on examining the return from  a 
>   stat(2)
>          system  call.

#### Second test

> The magic number tests are used to check for files with data in
>   particular fixed formats.

#### Third test

> The language tests look for particular strings (cf names.h) that can
>   appear
>          anywhere in the first few blocks of a file.  For example,  the  keyword
>          .br  indicates that the file is most likely a troff(1) input file, just
>          as the keyword struct indicates a C  program.

The output of the `file` command is generally based on the result of any of the tests that succeeds.

Now, assuming the C++ program starts like this, and the third test succeeds,

```
#include <iostream.h>
bla
bla
```

As per the third test the keyword `#include` particularly specifies it is of type **C** program though we have a **CPP** program in hand. Now, when I check,

```
$ file example.cpp

example.cpp: ASCII C program text
```

Now, the concepts of object oriented are specific to C++. Let us create a file specific to **C++**.

I start my C++ program as,

```
Class something
{
}
bla
bla
```

Now, when I issue

```
$ file example.cpp
```

The output is,

```
example.cpp: ASCII C++ program text
```

Comment: Of key note is the purpose of file is specific to identifying files by content alone.